# Is an OpenIdConnect MembershipProvider for SharePoint On Premise possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, sharepoint-2013, asp.net-membership, sharepoint-2016

I'm looking for a way to allow users to logon to SharePoint on-premise (SharePoint Foundation 2016) by means of OpenIdConnect (with Azure AD).

In the current situation we use a custom ASP.Net Membership provider which derives from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider. We do this so we can configure this membership provider in Central Administration / web.config.

While looking at code samples on how to implement OpenIdConnect, I noticed they're all stand-alone web projects, not class libraries like the MembershipProvider we're using right now.

- Do I need to derive from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider in order to make this work in SharePoint On-Premise / Foundation 2016?
- If so, can OpenIdConnect be made to work with such a MembershipProvider?
- If not, are there other ways to logon via Azure AD on SharePoint 2016?

What I've come up with so far:

- Implement a basic MembershipProvider (ValidateUser method) that communicates with a stand-alone web project via WCF / RESTful webservices.
- Let the stand-alone web project deal with OpenIdConnect / Azure AD.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Eddy